# data will not goto backend in mongodb using vue.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vue.js

backend will work when i using postman but when i using frontend for storing data only id will goes to database 
here my frontend code where i declare method:-

```
methods: {
feedbackData() {
  let KisanData1 = {
    name1: this.name1,
    village: this.village
  };
  console.log(KisanData1);
  axios
    .post('http://localhost:3000/User', KisanData1)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

backend code where i insert data:-

```
    app.post('/User', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  User.create(req.body).then((message) => {
    res.json(message);
  }).catch((error) => {
    res.status(500);
    res.json(error);
  });
});
```

and create method in mongodb:-

```
function create(message) {
const result = Joi.validate(message, UserSchema);
if (result.error==null) {
  message.created = new Date();
  return info.insert(message);
} else {
  return Promise.reject(result.error);
}
```

}

Comment: Try posting to just `/User`.

Comment: what i can't understand

Comment: i change but nothing happen

Comment: Are you getting any error messages in the network/console dev tools tabs?

Comment: no error in the network/console